# Rand() SQL function Randomizing Unnecessary Rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql = "SELECT phone, secques, secans, quesid FROM 2fa WHERE userid = '5' ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$c= $row["secques"];
$s= $row["phone"];
$t= $row["secans"];

  }
```

So I am creating an MFA webpage where a security question gets texted to the user's phone and they're supposed to enter the answer into an input box on the webpage. Each secques and secans are on corresponding rows in the mySQL table. When the rand function is called on the first line it randomizes both the secques and secans columns to where they are no longer on the corresponding row. So whenever I enter in my answer into the input box it is expecting a different answer since the answers have been randomized. Is there an alternative that just randomizes the rows as a whole instead of each individual column?

Comment: For those who can't guess: MFA = Multi Factor Authentication. I have no idea what "secques" and "secans" stand for, but they are columns in the database table "2fa". Obfuscation is bliss for a real programmer, isn't it? Anyway, back to the question. [ORDER BY RAND()](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-random-records-database-table.aspx) does not randomize columns, it only randomizes rows.

Comment: RAND() does only randomize the row, not the column. Maybe you're doing a rand each time you request it, so you're checking the given answer against the wrong question?

Comment: My secques = security question and my secans = security answer. I am assuming @aynber is right. Inside my while loop I am calling it individually each time causing the mismatch. Would there be any alternatives around this?

Comment: It could be that there are multiple rows for the user with `userid = '5'`. You first randomize and then limit the result to the first row. That first row can be different every time when there are multiple rows to choose from.

Comment: You need to store or pass the question id, probably in the session, so you can reference it once the security answer has been submitted.

Comment: I always try to convince people that they should write code that is comprehensible to other people. So if they see `secans` they might have no idea what it means. The alternative would be something like `securityAnswer`. Yes, it is longer, but that's not a negative thing, since now it is comprehensible. If you don't care about that you should be using `a`, `b`, and `c` as your names.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the output of this function is in the form of a decimal number, so that an integer can be entered, for example, a 6-digit integer can be used as follows, but my suggestion is to use the same php language to create a random number.

```
FLOOR(RAND()*(1000000))
```